# Different sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have two (2) arrays:

```
var stringArray = [Tom, Michael, Bob, Thomas];
var numberArray = [2, 3, 1, 4]
```

I need to sort stringArray for:

```
[Bob, Tom, Michael, Thomas]
```

How I can achieve this?

ect.

```
Bob = 1 in number array
Tom = 2 in number arra
Michael = 3 ....
```

Comment: What are you trying so far?

Comment: Why aren't your array values string-literals?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion with [Sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map)

```js
// the array to be sorted
var stringArray = ['Tom', 'Michael', 'Bob', 'Thomas'];
var numberArray = [2, 3, 1, 4];

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = stringArray.map(function (el, i) {
    return { index: i, value: numberArray[i] };
})

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.value - b.value;
});

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(function (el) {
    return stringArray[el.index];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution. No mapping..

```
    var numberArray = [2, 3, 1, 4];
    var stringArray = ["Tom", "Michael", "Bob", "Thomas"];
    var sorted = new Array();

for(var i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
    var order = numberArray[i] -1;
    var val = stringArray[order];
    sorted.push(val); 
}
console.log(sorted);
```

Your array should be this...

```
    var stringArray = ["Tom", "Michael", "Bob", "Thomas"];
```

instead of this

```
 var stringArray = [Tom, Michael, Bob, Thomas];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map your array items to objects containing values needed in sort and then map it back. (used ES6 syntax):

```
var stringArray = ["Tom", "Michael", "Bob", "Thomas"];
var numberArray = [2, 3, 1, 4]


var sorted = stringArray
              .map((item, index) => ({ value: item, order: numberArray[index] }))
              .sort((a, b) => a.order > b.order)
              .map(item => item.value);

console.log(sorted);
```

ES5 analogy:

```
var sorted = stringArray.map(function(item, index) {
    return { value: item, order: numberArray[index] };
}).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.order > b.order;
}).map(function(item) {
    return item.value;
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by zipping the two arrays together. Next, sorting them by their order. Then, mapping each item to a string. Finally, joining and printing the list.

```
Bob = 1 in number array
Tom = 2 in number array
Michael = 3 in number array
Thomas = 4 in number array
```

```js
var stringArray = ['Tom', 'Michael', 'Bob', 'Thomas'];
var numberArray = [2, 3, 1, 4];

document.body.innerHTML = zip([stringArray, numberArray]).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1] - b[1];
}).map(function(item) {
  return item[0] + ' = ' + item[1] + ' in number array';
}).join('<br />');

function zip(arrays) {
  return arrays[0].map(function(_, i) {
    return arrays.map(function(array) {
      return array[i];
    })
  });
}
```

---

You can create your own `zip()` function to reduce the values to an object.

```js
var stringArray = ['Tom', 'Michael', 'Bob', 'Thomas'];
var numberArray = [2, 3, 1, 4];

document.body.innerHTML = zip([stringArray, numberArray], ['name', 'order']).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.order - b.order;
}).map(function(item) {
  return item.name;
}).join(', ');

function zip(arrays, fields) {
  return arrays[0].map(function(_, i) {
    return arrays.map(function(array) {
      return array[i];
    }).reduce(function(obj, value, index) {
      obj[fields[index]] = value;
      return obj;
    }, {});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just map numberArray to get the stringArray element at each index

ES6

```
numberArray.map(n=>stringArray[n-1])
```

'regular JS'

```
numberArray.map(function(n){return stringArray[n-1]})
```

Answer (score 0):

numberArray[] is a rank (+1). This example creates another array I[], converting the rank+1 into sorted indices (0 to n-1), the reorders stringArray[] and I[] in place in O(n) time (each store places a value in it's final sorted position). C example, which should be convertible to javascript:

```
char * stringArray[] = {"Tom", "Michael", "Bob", "Thomas"};
int numberArray[] = {2, 3, 1, 4};
int I[4];                       // change 4 to array size
int i, j, k;
char * tS;                      // temp for stringArray element
    // convert rank+1 to sorted index I[]
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)      // change 4 to array size
        I[numberArray[i]-1] = i;
    // reorder stringArray in place
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){     // change 4 to array size
        if(i != I[i]){
            tS = stringArray[i];
            k = i;
            while(i != (j = I[k])){
                stringArray[k] = stringArray[j];
                I[k] = k;
                k = j;
            }
            stringArray[k] = tS;
            I[k] = k;
        }
    }
```